# Update certain values of a column from another dataframe based on condition of multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe1:

```
id    filler       ent    seg    val     text
1     M,0-10       CP     BEC    20       abc
2     M,10-20      D      BWC    30       abc
3     Y,0-10       CP     CCD    40       abc
4     Y,10-20      D      CFC    50       abc
```

dataframe2:

```
id    filler       ent    seg    val     text
1     M,0-10       CP     BEC    20       xyz
2     Y,10-20      D      CFC    50       xyz
```

need to create a
result dataframe:

```
id    filler       ent    seg    val     text
1     M,0-10       CP     BEC    20       xyz
2     M,10-20      D      BWC    30       abc
3     Y,0-10       CP     CCD    40       abc
4     Y,10-20      D      CFC    50       xyz
```

where its kind of checks whether all the columns apart from text have same value then updates dataframe1 by dataframe 2 my dataframe1 has 100 rows and dataframe2 has 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a left merge of dataframe2 onto dataframe1, and use the indicator column to find values that need updated in dataframe1.

```py
columns = ['id','filler','ent','seg','val','text']

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'M,0-10','CP','BEC',20, 'abc'],
    [2,'M,10-20','D','BWC',30,'abc'],
    [3,'Y,0-10','CP','CCD',40,'abc'],
    [4,'Y,10-20','D','CFC',50,'abc'],
], columns=columns)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'M,0-10','CP','BEC',20,'xyz'],
    [4,'Y,10-20','D','CFC',50,'xyz'],
], columns=columns)
```

Merge dataframe2 on dataframe1, with indicator column

```py
columns_merge = [x for x in columns if x!='text']
updated = df1.merge(df2, on=columns_merge, how='left', indicator=True)
```

Compare and set contents that need updated based on indicator column.

```py
same = updated['_merge']=='both'
updated.loc[same,'text_x'] = updated.loc[same,'text_y']
```

Drop & rename columns

```py
updated.drop(columns=['text_y','_merge'], inplace=True)
updated.rename(columns = {'text_x': 'text'}, inplace=True)
```

updated =

```py
   id   filler ent  seg  val text
0   1   M,0-10  CP  BEC   20  xyz
1   2  M,10-20   D  BWC   30  abc
2   3   Y,0-10  CP  CCD   40  abc
3   4  Y,10-20   D  CFC   50  xyz
```

Comment: HI Jason,
Thanks for answering I have only one issue that I am facing I am getting the number of rows increased eg: my data has 112 rows in df1 and 24 rows in df2 but my updated dataframe is 120rows.Please help me on this

Comment: Try df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','filler','ent','seg','val','text']) and check the resulting row count. It will be less than 24 rows.

Comment: Because of how the merge function is used here (the position of df1, df2, and how=left), the merge result would include one row for every row in df1, if there were no duplicates in df2. In your case, there are record(s) in df1 that match multiple records in df2 and the resulting merge includes these duplicated records.